# Tracking user from adwords ads to form submit

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-ads-api

So a client asked me to create a Conversion tracking

He said this:

> Can you create a Conversion on Analytics for us? We would like to
>   track how many of the users that clicked on an adword submits the form on the contact page.

I Created a conversion code tracking on AdWords and used this little script to track the user:

```
jQuery('form').submit(function() {
    var google_conversion_id = 123456789;
    var google_conversion_label = 'das098das098ads809';
    var image = new Image(1,1);
    image.src = 'http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/'+google_conversion_id+'/imp.gif?value=0&label='+google_conversion_label+'&guid=ON&script=0';
});
```

And now I'm wondering if this is what he asked for? Will this track users from the ads?
I have never worked with adwords before so I am a bit confused on all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the only image conversion code ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4keF.png)), what you have should work (condensed below).

```
jQuery('form').submit(function () {
    new Image().src = 'REPLACE_WITH_IMG_URL';
});
```

If you have the javascript code version ([example](https://gist.github.com/3912154)) AND there is a "Thank You for contacting us" page, you're better off pasting the original code on that page as you more information sent back to Adwords from running the javascript file (which generates a more detailed image request w/ browser size etc...) rather than the inline image request above.

FYI Code you have above in orig answer should work.

Comment: I followed this guide: http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1722054 and I only got a little code snippet: http://i.imgur.com/VnYQM.png